# How to handle corrosion near HVAC system?

Tags: hvac, corrosion

It seems that there is some bushing missing around the gas line of the HVAC system (Rheem installed in 2015). Below the gas line there is some corrosion on the unit.

I have two questions:

1. Is the corrosion related to the missing bushing?
2. How should I repair or manage this corrosion in the future?

[image: hvac corrosion, gas line missing busshing]

Comment: where do you think is the water coming from ?

Comment: Can you show a photo with more of the equipment and its venting visible? Water around a furnace can come from a variety of related sources (eg exhaust condensate, air conditioning condensate, humidifier) or unrelated sources (water plumbing, drains, roof leak, etc).

Comment: Did you ever find the water source?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response MonkeyZeus. I'm so terribly sorry for the delay in responding to you. Personal life got in the way of me getting back here, but I truly appreciate your time and detailed answers. 

I've yet to determine the source of the water. There is one part of the air conditioning unit that I would like to post a picture of, which might be a culprit.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. If you post a new question about the A/C part then make sure to include a good picture. My initial theory is that the main drain is clogged so the overflow drain is leaking onto your equipment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sincerely doubt the corrosion has anything to do with the flex gas line or missing bushing. Unless the photo angle is deceiving, that corrosion isn't even beneath the gas line; it seems to be a good 1-2 inches to the left of it.

Water should **NOT** be coming out of that hole. If it is then you have bigger problems than a missing bushing.

The water is likely dripping from the ceiling, or at least it was at one point.

[image]

---

Anyways, the missing bushing is important and a sign of bad workmanship. If the flex hose is disturbed and rubs against the sharp metal then it could cause a gas leak.

The installer should have used black iron inside the furnace and made the flex connection from the outside. See below for a picture of how it should look.

So yes, the missing bushing is an issue but not in the way you guessed.

[image]

Comment: Minor quibble: you're correct that gas flex passing through the wall of the appliance violates code. But locating the flex entirely outside the appliance is not the only option: it's also acceptable to have the flex entirely inside the appliance cabinet. Either way, as you said black iron pipe is the way to go through the appliance wall.

Comment: @GregHill I assume you're right but I offer you this: "We were so preoccupied with whether or not we could that we didn't stop to think if we should."